# Make the div take all the remaining width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a header, which has a hamburger menu, a search input and a notification button. The hamburger menu will be on the left side, notification button will be on the right side, and search input will be on the middle.

```css
.general_button {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    background: #2ec76e;
    padding: 5px;
}

header i {
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}

header #hamburger_menu {
    float: left;
}

header #notification_btn {
    float: right;
}

header #search_btn .general_button {
    padding-right: 0;
}

header #search_btn {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

header #search_btn input {
    font-size: 14pt;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    color: white;
}

header #header-wrapper #search_btn input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
  color: #92e6b6;
}

header #header-wrapper #search_btn input:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  color: #92e6b6;
  opacity: 1;
}

header #header-wrapper #search_btn input::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  color: #92e6b6;
  opacity: 1;
}

header #header-wrapper #search_btn input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: #92e6b6;
}

header #search_btn hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #92e6b6;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
  <div id="header-wrapper">
    <div id="hamburger_menu" class="nav">
      <button class="general_button"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="notification_btn">
      <button class="general_button"><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="search_btn">
      <button class="general_button"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
      <span class="clear_both"></span>
      <hr/>
    </div>
    <span class="clear_both"></span>
  </div>
</header>
```

[codepen.io](http://codepen.io/Benjaminsmith5050/pen/kXyjjz)

The menu and the notification button takes only a small part of the width. For the `search-btn` div I gave a width of 60%. However I would like the `search-btn` div take all the width that is left. How can I do that?

Comment: `width: auto; overflow: hidden` ?

Comment: @Oriol That makes the `<hr/>` take the whole width of the header.

Comment: You might want to check out flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

Try using flexbox, remove all the floats, set the container to `#header-wrapper {display:flex;}` and set the middle column to `#search_btn {flex:1;}` to make it to take all the space remaining. You can reorder the items by adding `#notification_btn {order:1;}`, if you don't want to update the HTML.

I also suggest to use flexbox for the search input the button as well, use a bottom border rather than using `<hr>`. And you won't need clear the floats since it's all flexbox.

```css
.general_button {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    background: #2ec76e;
    padding: 5px;
}

header i {
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}

header #header-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

header #hamburger_menu {
    /* float: left; */
}

header #notification_btn {
    /* float: right; */
    order: 1;
}

header #search_btn .general_button {
    padding-right: 0;
}

header #search_btn {
    /* width: 60%; */
    /* margin: 0 auto; */
    /* display: block; */
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #92e6b6;
}

header #search_btn input {
    font-size: 14pt;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    color: white;
    flex: 1;
}

header #header-wrapper #search_btn input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #92e6b6;
}

header #header-wrapper #search_btn input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #92e6b6;
  opacity: 1;
}

header #header-wrapper #search_btn input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #92e6b6;
}

/* header #search_btn hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #92e6b6;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
} */
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
  <div id="header-wrapper">
    <div id="hamburger_menu" class="nav">
      <button class="general_button"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div id="notification_btn">
      <button class="general_button"><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div id="search_btn">
      <button class="general_button"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
      <!-- <span class="clear_both"></span> -->
      <!-- <hr/> -->
    </div>
    <!-- <span class="clear_both"></span> -->
  </div>
</header>
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m1vL62qg/)**

Answer (score 0):

Calc will probably work:

width: calc(100% - 80px);

Replace 80px with whatever the width of your other elements is

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Answer (score 0):

You know that your notification and hamburger buttons are 40px wide, so you can just use a CSS calculation to fill in the rest!

```
header #search_btn{
  width:calc(100% - 80px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just remove your width:60%; and set "header #search_btn" to have an overflow:auto;.

```
header #search_btn {    
overflow:auto;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
}
```